# How to create the custom marker in slf4j/log4j2?

Tags: logging, slf4j, log4j2

I am trying to create custom marker using slf4j and log4j2. Below is how I created the marker and used it:

```
Marker marker = org.slf4j.MarkerFactory.getMarker("WebService");
logger.info(marker, "service called");
```

And below is my log4j2-test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="layout">%d | %-5p | [%t] | %c{2} | %M | %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <File name="WebServices" fileName="${sys:user.home}/logs/service_requests.log">
            <MarkerFilter marker="WebService" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
            <JSONLayout>
            </JSONLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="WebServices" level="INFO" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It created the file but does not write anything to it. Did I miss something? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the noise, it's working as expected now, it seems like the problem was jar files, I deleted all jars and ran mvn build again